# What does "I pissed the wall" mean?

Tags: meaning, verbs

What is the meaning of a sentence like "I pissed the wall"?
Is there any difference with "I pissed my pants"?

Comment: Can you give any extra context?  Out of context it sounds ungrammatical to me, and my best guess would be that it’s an error for a phrase like the one @D_Bye mentions, which would normally include some preposition(s).

Comment: @PLL: Would "I heard somebody that was in the restrooms saying that" be enough as context? I am sure of what I have heard; I am not sure of how I should interpret the sentence.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZoP9AsrRF_Y

Comment: How about "I pissed off the wall"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can see four possibilities:

- It’s an idiomatic figurative usage, analogous to something like *I was shitting bricks*.  This seems very unlikely: none of us here seem to have heard any such usage, and Google doesn’t find anything.
- It’s a literal usage, meaning “I pissed on the wall” (which is how most English-speakers would say it), but is correct in this speaker’s dialect/idiolect.  This seems fairly unlikely, for the same reasons as before.
- It’s not idiomatic, and is deliberate wordplay.  There are a few idioms that this is analogous to, like “to piss the bed” or “to piss one’s pants”, and the speaker might have been jokingly adapting one of these.
- It’s not idiomatic, and is a speech error, intended as “I pissed on the wall”, or similar.  This seems the most likely to me — especially since if the speaker had actually just *?pissed the wall* then he may well have been somewhat inebriated at the time…

Comment: I think it is either 2 or 4. Hard to tell the difference for an outsider.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean "I pissed it up [against] the wall"? It's an idiom that roughly means to squander or waste, as in money, an opportunity, etc.

Comment: I wrote the full sentence.

Comment: My apologies - it's not a usage I've ever encountered before.

Comment: The use of this term refers particularly to wasting money at the pub.  To squander on Alcohol.

Answer (score 3):

I think that it means you urinated on the wall.

Comment: You cannot urinate a wall any more than you can defecate a house.

Comment: @Ed: well, some things may be physically impossible but figuratively idiomatic.  One can certainly shit bricks!  But “pissing the wall” isn’t an idiom I’ve ever heard, nor anything similar with pissing…

Comment: I have updated my assertion.

Answer (score 2):

It comes from the Bible (King James Edition):

> Behold, I will bring evil upon thee, and will take away thy posterity, and will cut off from Ahab him that pisseth against the wall, and him that is shut up and left in Israel,

Comment: 2 KIngs 9:7–10: "And thou shalt smite the house of Ahab thy master, that I may avenge the blood of my servants the prophets, and the blood of all the servants of the Lord, at the hand of Jezebel. For the whole house of Ahab shall perish: and I will cut off from Ahab him that pisseth against the wall, and him that is shut up and left in Israel: and I will make the house of Ahab like the house of Jeroboam the son of Nebat, and like the house of Baasha the son of Ahija: and the dogs shall eat Jezebel in the portion of Jezreel, and there shall be none to bury her. And he opened the door and fled."

Comment: The language in my quotation is from [_The Cambridge Bible for Schools & Colleges: Kings I. II._](https://books.google.com/books?id=0PY8AAAAIAAJ&pg=RA1-PA87&dq=%22will+cut+off+from+Ahab+him%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC4Q6AEwA2oVChMI2dj90Mz5xwIVkDKICh2cSA6u#v=onepage&q=%22will%20cut%20off%20from%20Ahab%20him%22&f=false) I upvoted this answer because, unlike the earlier one citing instances from the Bible, it provided an instance in the body of the answer, rather than just links. The answer would be stronger if it explained the connection (if any) between the biblical precedent and the OP's phrase.

Answer (score 1):

In biblical usage, it means that you are male.

(See 1 Samuel 25:22, 34; 1 Kings 14:10, 16:11, 21:21; 2 Kings 9:8)

Comment: Does the Bible use a phrase like "pissed the wall"?

Comment: I just gave you six references...

Comment: @PoC those references (at least the first one that I checked) use the phrase "pissed *against* the wall" not "pissed the wall".

Comment: @Ed I didn't realize that was an important distinction in his question.

Comment: @PoC He's quoted it, and emphasised the exact quote, so it does seem to be an important distinction. It would be a trivial question otherwise.

Comment: @Peter: I’d agree with Ed that I don’t think this answers the question at hand — but thanks for pointing out a lovely euphemism (or is it a dysphemism?) that I hadn’t come across before!

Comment: @PLL I'm pretty sure it's a dysphemism

Answer (score 1):

It means to waste one's money. As in, "I wasted all my paycheque on beer and now I've got nothing. I pissed it up the wall!"

Answer (score 1):

As stated above - "He pissed it up a wall" means he wasted his money - ie, he spent it on beer which went through his system and he pissed it all away.  "The wall" was/is a feature of pub gents' toilets in England.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. To support an existing answer, upvote it using the up-arrow icon to its left. If you are not familiar with Stack Exchange, I encourage you to visit the [Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help); this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 0):

As a foreign English speaker, I think the verb 'piss' can be used as a transitive verb (at least in my native language), it means piss and make something dirty.

Comment: What do you mean, like that you could piss the white walls yellow?

Answer (score 0):

"I've pissed it up the wall." It means I have no money or I'm worth nothing if I die. I've drank my money away in the pub and there is nothing left. Direct quote of an unknown SAS officer: "You were supposed to have written a will but I didn't...I paid lip service to that, I didn't have a fuckin will. There wasn't anything left to fuckin have anyways, I just pissed it up the wall."

Comment: Can you provide any sort of reference?